# Script throws some error at some point within the execution

Tags: python, web-scraping, puppeteer, pyppeteer, python-asyncio

I've created a script in python using ***[pyppeteer](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/)*** to collect the links of different posts from a webpage and then parse the title of each post by going in their target page reusing those collected links. Although the content are static, I like to know how pyppeteer works in such cases.

I tried to supply this `browser` variable from `main()` function to `fetch()` and `browse_all_links()` function so that I can reuse the same browser over and over again.

My current approach:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

async def fetch(page,url):
    await page.goto(url)
    linkstorage = []
    await page.waitForSelector('.summary .question-hyperlink')
    elements = await page.querySelectorAll('.summary .question-hyperlink')
    for element in elements:
        linkstorage.append(await page.evaluate('(element) => element.href', element))
    return linkstorage

async def browse_all_links(page,link):
    await page.goto(link)
    await page.waitForSelector('h1 > a')
    title = await page.querySelectorEval('h1 > a','(e => e.innerText)')
    print(title)

async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=False,autoClose=False)
    [page] = await browser.pages()
    links = await fetch(page,url)
    tasks = [await browse_all_links(page,url) for url in links]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The above script fetches some titles but spits out the following error at some point within the execution:

```
Possible to select <a> with specific text within the quotes?
Crawler Runs Too Slow
How do I loop a list of ticker to scrape balance sheet info?
How to retrive the url of searched video from youtbe using python
VBA-JSON to import data from all pages in one table
Is there an algorithm that detects semantic visual blocks in a webpage?
find_all only scrape the last value

#ERROR STARTS

Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error (Runtime.releaseObject): Cannot find context with specified id')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error (Runtime.releaseObject): Cannot find context with specified id
Future exception was never retrieved
```

Comment: I see you are fetching `href`. This might not be complete `url` i.e. it might be `/contact` instead of `http://www.example.com/contact`. There is no protocol specified in the earlier case and thus it throws an error is what I suspect.

Comment: You are wrong @Vishnudev. When any browser simulator comes into play, most of the cases the retrieved urls are complete, as in what I see in this very case.

Comment: Oh okay. I just suspected. If links work fine then I have no idea why this is the case.

Comment: I've never even heard of this toolkit but the first Google result I looked at seems relevant. Starting with [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1325#issuecomment-395472092) comment.

Comment: @robots.txt why do you use [tag:asyncio] tag? there is already existing [tag:python-asyncio] tag with 2000+ questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS it's been two days since this question has been posted but no one yet to answer, I will take this opportunity to address this issue what I
think might be helpful to you.

- There are 15 links but you are getting only 7, this is probably websockets is loosing connection and page is not reachable anymore
- List comprehension

tasks = `[await browse_all_links(page,url) for url in links]` What do expect is this list? If it's succesful, it will be a list
of none element. So your next line of code will throw error!

- Solution

  downgrade websockets 7.0 to websockets 6.0

  remove this line of code `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`

  I am using python 3.6, so I had to change last line of code.
  You don't need change it if you are using python 3.7 which I think you are using

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

async def fetch(page,url):
    await page.goto(url)
    linkstorage = []
    await page.waitForSelector('.summary .question-hyperlink')
    elements = await page.querySelectorAll('.summary .question-hyperlink')
    for element in elements:
        linkstorage.append(await page.evaluate('(element) => element.href', element))
    return linkstorage

async def browse_all_links(page,link):
    await page.goto(link)
    await page.waitForSelector('h1 > a')
    title = await page.querySelectorEval('h1 > a','(e => e.innerText)')
    print(title)
async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=False,autoClose=False)
    [page] = await browser.pages()
    links = await fetch(page,url)
    tasks = [await browse_all_links(page,url) for url in links]
    #await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    await browser.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #asyncio.run(main())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

- Output

(testenv) C:\Py\pypuppeteer1>python stack3.py
Scrapy Shell response.css returns an empty array
Scrapy real-time spider
Why do I get KeyError while reading data with get request?
Scrapy spider can't redefine custom_settings according to args
Custom JS Script using Lua in Splash UI
Can someone explain why and how this piece of code works [on hold]
How can I extract required data from a list of strings?
Scrapy CrawlSpider rules for crawling single page
how to **scrape** a web-page with search bar results, when the search query does not
appear in the url
Nested for loop keeps repeating
Get all tags except a list of tags BeautifulSoup
Get current URL using Python and webbot
How to login to site and send data
Unable to append value to colums. Getting error IndexError: list index out of ra
nge
NextSibling.Innertext not working. “Object doesn't support this property”

Comment: Your solution appears to be working but it is working inconsistently. When I try couple of times, the script gets stuck just before the last or second last result throwing `pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000 ms exceeded.`. You advised me not to remove last line of code. Is this line what you meant `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` not to remove? Finally, I really don't know how can I downgrade `websockets 7.0 to websockets 6.0`. Btw, how did you know I'm using python 3.7? Thanks.

Comment: No, you remove `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` and let me know.

Comment: `asyncio.run(main())` is only applicable python 3.7 or above. You have used this line of code in your test, thats why I guessed I may be using python 3.7

Comment: I didn't use `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` when I gave you the feedback. Can I not just use `try/except` clause to handle that error? However, I don't know how to use error handler in asyncio pattern. Btw, is it necessary to downgrade websockets 7.0 to websockets 6.0? If it is then how? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am using python 3.6, for me its necessary to downgrade websockets 7 to 6. Give it a try. `python -m uninstall websockets` then  `python -m install websockets== 6.0`

Comment: I got the script working now by using `try/except` clause to get rid of `timeout` error. Does `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` lead me to degrade performane If I not use that as that very line works how `multithreading/multiprocessing` does? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please take [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56668605/unable-to-let-my-script-perform-all-the-clicks-on-the-next-page-button) a look in case there is any solution to offer @TwinckleTwinckle. Thanks.

Comment: There is a fork of pyppeteer, pyppeteer2, that has fixed these issues.